# Teste com Expresso no Android retorna null para mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindowManager()

Tags: java, android

Obtenho erro quando tento acessar a propriedade da activity  mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

tentei alterar IntentsTestRule ao invés de ActivityTestRule e nada.

tentei chamar InstrucoesActivityTest2.class ao invés de InstrucoesActivity.class e nada

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class InstrucoesActivityTest2 {

```
@Rule public IntentsTestRule<InstrucoesActivity> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<InstrucoesActivity>(
        InstrucoesActivity.class,false, false){
    @Override
    protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
        Receita receita = new Receita();
        receita.setId(1);
        receita.setName("Nutella Pie");
        receita.setServings(8);
        receita.setImage("");
        receita.setIngredients(null);
        receita.setSteps(null);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("receita", receita);
        Intent intent = new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(),InstrucoesActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        return intent;
    }

};


@Before
public void init(){
    mActivityRule.getActivity ()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //assumeTrue(isScreenSw600dp());
    assumeTrue(!isScreenSw600dp());
}


@Test public void test(){
    assumeTrue(isScreenSw600dp());
    onView(withId(R.id.container_instrucoes)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}


private boolean isScreenSw600dp() {
    //Intents.init();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    float widthDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    float heightDp = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    float screenSw = Math.min(widthDp, heightDp);

   // Intents.release();
    return screenSw >= 600;
}

public int getScreenOrientation(){
    Display getOrient = mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    if(getOrient.getWidth()==getOrient.getHeight()){
        orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
    } else{
        if(getOrient.getWidth() < getOrient.getHeight()){
            orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }else {
            orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        }
    }
    return orientation;
}
```

}
```

obtendo erros

```Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.studiotopdev.culinaria.InstrucoesActivityTest2 com.studiotopdev.culinaria.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.WindowManager com.studiotopdev.culinaria.InstrucoesActivity.getWindowManager()' on a null object reference
at com.studiotopdev.culinaria.InstrucoesActivityTest2.isScreenSw600dp(InstrucoesActivityTest2.java:81)
at com.studiotopdev.culinaria.InstrucoesActivityTest2.setUp(InstrucoesActivityTest2.java:68)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:433)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
```